# ¿Como puedo modificar un campo que integer y volverlo null o vacio? desde laravel en DB postgresql

Tags: laravel-5, laravel, postgresql

La tabla es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE public.productos_procesos
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('productos_procesos_id_seq'::regclass),
  id_productos integer NOT NULL,
  id_procesos integer NOT NULL,
  unidad_teorica integer,
  id_unidades_de_medicion integer,
  velocidad integer,
  created_at timestamp(0) without time zone,
  updated_at timestamp(0) without time zone,
  tiempo_teorico character varying(255) DEFAULT '0:0:0'::character varying,
  valid boolean DEFAULT true,
}
```

Y cuando intento modificar un campo de tipo entero y volverla null me lanza el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para integer: «» (SQL: update "productos_procesos" set "unidad_teorica" = , "id_unidades_de_medicion" = , "velocidad" = , "updated_at" = 2017-03-15 17:52:13, "valid" = false where "id" = 121)

Controllador:

```
$result = Productos_Procesos::findOrFail($req->productos[$i]);
$valores = array(
    'valid' => $req->valid[$i],
    'unidad_teorica' => $req->unidad_teorica[$i],
    'id_unidades_de_medicion' => $req->unidad_de_medicion[$i],
    'velocidad' => $req->velocidad[$i],
    'tiempo_teorico' => $req->tiempo_teorico[$i],
);
$result->update($valores);
```

El array que creo es el siguiente:

```
array:5 [
  "valid" => "false"
  "unidad_teorica" => ""
  "id_unidades_de_medicion" => ""
  "velocidad" => ""
  "tiempo_teorico" => ""
]
```

Comment: Pareciera no ser relevante, pero lo puede ser ¿qué versión de Laravel usas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu array deberua ir **null** en ves de estar vacio **""**

```
array:5 [
  "valid" => "false"
  "unidad_teorica" => null //envias la variable como null y no como vacío
  "id_unidades_de_medicion" => ""
  "velocidad" => ""
 "tiempo_teorico" => ""
```

]

Comment: gracias, efectivamente funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Como referencia para otras futuros visitantes, a partir de Laravel 5.4 existe un middleware que se encarga de convertir los strings vacíos de un request en null, y así evitar este tipo de inconvenientes.

Aunque la respuesta escogida es correcta, de cara al futuro la mejor práctica (al menos hasta este momento) es usar el middleware.

Dicho middleware se llama `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` y viene incluído por defecto en el stack localizado en `App\Http\Kernel`.

El código de dicho middleware es el siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware;

class ConvertEmptyStringsToNull extends TransformsRequest
{
    /**
     * Transform the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function transform($key, $value)
    {
        return is_string($value) && $value === '' ? null : $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: interesante! gracias Shaz.